# Makes sense to call stored procedure as prepared statement?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have SQL Server stored procedure to insert or update some data (do some logic). I want to call it from .net application multiple times to insert/update many rows.

Does it make sense to call stored procedure as prepared statement, when stored procedure is already compiled and expecting just parameters?

Comment: yes, of course. It is also surely a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any stored procedure, like a **parametrized query**, too, will have to be **parsed** once before it's executed by SQL Server.

During that parsing, an **execution plan** is determined and stored in the plan cache of SQL Server, and any subsequent calls to that stored procedure (or parametrized query) will reuse that cached execution plan. That cached execution plan stays in memory until SQL Server restarts, or until the cache has to be cleared out due to memory pressure.

So basically - there's no way around the fact that the stored procedure (or parametrized query) will have to be **parsed once** (to determine the execution plan) - once that's done, the execution plan is in memory and can be reused. This also means: the first call to a stored procedure (since the last SQL Server restart) will always be a bit slower - after all, more work needs to be performed - and any subsequent calls should be noticeably faster.

Comment: So, should I use prepared statement? Helps it to run more effectively?

Comment: @Fanda: yes, of course - a *prepared statement* basically just runs through the initial parse phase and after that, the stored procedure/parametrized query is available for execution for subsequent calls.